# jquery get value from ID list

Tags: jquery

I have a list of ids

```
Idlist=["id_SP_0", "id_SP_1", "id_SP_2", "id_SP_3"]
```

I was trying to get the id such as `$('#id_SP_2').val()`

How can I get the values from the list? I have tried: `$(Idlist[i].val())`, it didn't work.

Comment: `$('#' + Idlist[i]).val()`

Answer (score 1):

Map the array of IDs to an array of values

```js
const values = Idlist.map(id => $(`#${id}`).val())
```

You could do this just as easily without jQuery

```js
const values = Idlist.map(id => document.getElementById(id).value)
```

---

If you wanted something more like a map of IDs to values, use a *reduce* operation instead

```js
const valueMap = Idlist.reduce((map, id) => ({
  ...map,
  [ id ]: document.getElementById(id).value
}), {})
```